# Refactoring in Eclipse/Java: Apply "Extract Method" (Alt+Shift+M) afterwards

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

I wish to know if this is possible to replace some code by a call to the method extracted earlier.

For example, I have a class with similar patterns:

```
public class ExtractMethodDemo {
    public void doSequence() {
        long n1; n2;
        // Compute and print count
        n1 = 70;
        n2 = compute(n1);                                        // <-- 1st
        System.out.printf("Input %4s, output = %s.%n", n1, n2);  // <-- occurrence
        ....
        // Compute and print count again
        n2 = n2 % 100;
        n1 = compute(n2);                                        // <-- Nth
        System.out.printf("Input %4s, output = %s.%n", n2, n1);  // <-- occurrence
    }
}
```

I [refactor using a method](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-ExtractMethod.htm) but for some reason some occurrences are still not refactored (possible if `Replace additional occurrences...` is unchecked, or if same code is pasted later):

```
public void doSequence() {
    long n1; n2;
    // Compute and print count
    n1 = 70;
    n2 = doAll(n1);                                          // <--- method extracted
    // ....
    // Compute and print count again
    n2 = n2 % 100;
    n1 = compute(n2);                                        // <--- oops! this one is
    System.out.printf("Input %4s, output = %s.%n", n2, n1);  // <--- still old style
}

private long doAll(long n) {
    long n2; // (BTW: not the n2 declared in doSequence!)
    n2 = compute(n);
    System.out.printf("Input %4s, output = %s.%n", n, n2);
    return n2;
}
```

Is it possible to have reamining sequences refactored afterwards:

```
public void doSequence() {
    long n1; n2;
    // Compute and print count
    n1 = 70;
    n2 = doAll(n1);
    // ....
    // Compute and print count again
    n2 = n2 % 100;
    n1 = doAll(n2);    // <--- would be great to apply same refactoring afterwards
}
```

Comment: As a last resort, I could re-inline all code, and extract the method again, but that not elegant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a tiny bit better than re-inlining the code would be to Extract Method on the entire body of the new code, with `Replace Additional Occurrences` checked, and then inline the new method from the original call.  That way you run less risk of choosing the wrong lines to extract.

**Update:** Here's an example:

You start with

```
extractableCode(1);
extractableCode(2);
extractableCode(3);
```

and extract the original block, leaving you with

```
extractedMethod(1);
extractableCode(2);
extractableCode(3);
...
function extractedMethod(int i) {
    extractableCode(i);
}
```

Your way would be to inline extractedMethod, then repeat the extraction with Replace All Occurrences.  I'm suggesting instead that you extract from inside `extractedMethod()`:

```
extractedMethod(1);
secondExtractedMethod(2);
secondExtractedMethod(3);
...
function extractedMethod(int i) {
    secondExtractedMethod(i);
}
function secondExtractedMethod(int i) {
    extractableCode(i);
}
```

Then inline your original call to the first extracted method:

```
secondExtractedMethod(1);
secondExtractedMethod(2);
secondExtractedMethod(3);
...
function secondExtractedMethod(int i) {
    extractableCode(i);
}
```

And then, probably rename the second extracted method.  It's only a tiny bit different from what you originally suggest, but it might be a little more reliable.

Comment: Thanks. Forgive me, I don't understand the sequence of actions, in particular what is "entire body of the new code). In my example... 1. I select the two forgotten lines (Nth occurrence) 2. Extract to a new method (e.g. doAll2). 3. ?